# Control rendering of PDF

Tags: pdf, sharepoint-2013, word-automation-service

Using Word Automation Services, I have some very simple code like this:

```
SyncConverter sync = new SyncConverter(wordAutomationServiceName);
sync.Settings.OutputFormat = input.Format;
sync.Settings.UpdateFields = true;
ConversionItemInfo convInfo = sync.Convert(input.StreamData, ms);
```

When input.Format is Word, images look great. But when it's PDF, the images look like they've been smoothed and it ends up looking a little fuzzy. Are there any options anywhere that can control how images get converted into a PDF? All my images are basically line drawings (charts and maps) so I really don't need any smoothing applied.

Here's a comparison of the same image in a pdf (left) and word (right).

[image: Comparison]

Comment: Word handles your average bitmap image really, really bad - and vectors even worse.  Are you sure that the right hand image is not also a bitmap? It may have silently converted the image on importing! (Which also could indicate why it got even further downsampled when exporting.)

Comment: @Jongware: They are included as bitmaps. Basically I create the word document then run it through WAS to update fields (and flatten alt parts) and then it is either returned as a DOCX (right) or a PDF (left).

Comment: Sorry - your "basically line drawings" threw me off then. In bitmaps, Line Drawing ≠ Infinitely Scaleable and Sharp! Especially on lines that don't follow the pixel grid; a slanted line will always either alias badly or suffer from well-intended antialiasing. Still, it seems some resampling is going on from one version to the other.

Comment: @Jongware: Sorry, I meant line drawing as in they ought to be PNG rather than JPEG which would obviously look horrible.